# Spring Boot - using Externalized Configuration values in @Configuration classes

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I needed to externalize our session storage, so have used spring-session.

Following their examples at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session/blob/master/samples/boot/src/main/java/sample/config/EmbeddedRedisConfiguration.java, I created my `EmbeddedRedisConfiguration` and everything works as it should.

I decided that I wanted optional support to specify the Redis executable path, in the case of pre existing local redis server, so I have added to `/resources/config/application.properties` the following key value `redis.embedded.executable.path==/path/to/redis`.

My immediate thought was then to just use @Value annotation in my configuration, and have access to the value

```
static class RedisServerBean implements InitializingBean, DisposableBean, BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
    private RedisServer redisServer;

    @Value("${redis.embedded.executable.path}")
    String executablePath;

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if (executablePath != null) {
            redisServer = new RedisServer(new File(executablePath), Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT);    
        } else {
            redisServer = new RedisServer(Protocol.DEFAULT_PORT);
        }
        redisServer.start();
    }

    public void destroy() throws Exception {
        if(redisServer != null) {
            redisServer.stop();
        }
    }

    public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {}

    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {}
}
```

However, `executablePath` is always null. As you know, if you use an `@Value` in a `@Service` class or equivalent, the value will be populated.

I assume that this configuration is being invoked before the beans that load the properties, but I also know this is possible, because eg `@DatasourceAutoConfiguration` can use `spring.datasource.*` properties

I am obviously overlooking something simple here. Do I require my own `@ConfigurationProperties`

Comment: can you show us your configuration file? is this bean actually managed by Spring?

Comment: this configuration file is identical to the link provided above, with the addition of my `@Value` annotated field

Comment: Why do you need a `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`? It's causing the early instantiation before the `@Value` can be bound.

Comment: That was it. I guess that is what happens with copy paste, even from official sources :)

Answer (score -1):

Change your property file to:

```
redis.embedded.executable.path=/path/to/redis
```

Comment: my question states that I have added this to my `application.properties`

Comment: you have two equal signs kabal

Comment: this is an answer Rüdiger. kabal has an error in the property file and I'm fixing it

Comment: the extra = is just a config value misconfiguration, not the cause of the null value.